# Set the size of text in ListView

Tags: android

I want to set the text size of the `ListView`. I am not use the XML Layout file.

How to do this in coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to modify text size of the default `ListView`.

I would recommend creating or editing your adapter and overriding the `getView` method with something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent,
                                        false);
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

            YourModel model = getItem(position);
            holder.text.setText(model.getText());

            return convertView;
 }
```

And in your xml you can set the size correctly.

If you didn't watch [The world of ListView by Romain Guy, Adam Powell](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) do it.

Comment: @DattaKunde give thanks by accepting answer..not by writing comment

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found your textview you have access to all it's attributes.
So, changing the typeface or style is as simple as the following snippet:

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
holder.text.setTextSize(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Layout height and weight as your requirement.